# Android room database, replace element by id

Tags: android, android-room, android-database

How to replace existed object by id in the room?
For example, I have User with id **7** and name *John*. Then I change name to *Bob*.
How to **update** or **replace** it by id in the room?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the update annotation in your Dao, it would update based on the primary key (id in your case)

```
@Update()
void updateUser(User user);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [REPLACE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/OnConflictStrategy.html#replace) strategy on conflict and declare insert method this way:

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertUser(user: User)
}
```